# How can I rearrange the array so that the null values take up the beginning of the array?

Tags: java, arrays, string

I'm not sure how to add the null elements to the front of the array.

Is there any way to do this without reversing the array? A specific method, perhaps?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] stringArray = new String[]{"one", "two", "three"};
    method(stringArray);
}

public static String[] method(String[] stringArray) {
    String[] biggerStringArray = Arrays.copyOf(stringArray, stringArray.length * 2);

    for (int i = 0; i < biggerStringArray.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(biggerStringArray[i] + ", ");

    }

    return biggerStringArray;
}
```

I want the result to look like:

> null, null, null, one, two, three,

instead of :

> one, two, three, null, null, null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] stringArray = new String[] {"one", "two", "three"};
    method(stringArray);
  }

  public static String[] method(String[] stringArray) {
    String[] biggerStringArray = new String[stringArray.length * 2];

    for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++) {
      biggerStringArray[i + biggerStringArray.length / 2] = stringArray[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < biggerStringArray.length; i++) {
      System.out.print(biggerStringArray[i] + ", ");
    }
    return biggerStringArray;
  }
```

EDIT: Just remembered you can also use [System.arraycopy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int)):

```
public static String[] method(String[] stringArray) {
    String[] biggerStringArray = new String[stringArray.length * 2];

    System.arraycopy(stringArray, 0, biggerStringArray, biggerStringArray.length / 2, stringArray.length);

    for (int i = 0; i < biggerStringArray.length; i++) {
      System.out.print(biggerStringArray[i] + ", ");
    }
    return biggerStringArray;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, a single statement which does what you are looking for does not exist. That doesn't mean that you can't do it yourself though. There are lots of ways to swap elements in an array. Here's one:

```
String[] biggerStringArray = Arrays.copyOf(stringArray, stringArray.length * 2);
for(int i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++)
{
    biggerStringArray[i] = biggerStringArray[i + stringArray.length];
    biggerStringArray[i + stringArray.length] = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own `copy` method, like this

```
    public static String[] copyArray(String[] array, int length) {
        String[] biggerStringArray = new String[length];
        for (int i = 1; i <= array.length; i++) {
            biggerStringArray[biggerStringArray.length - i] = array[array.length - i];
        }
        return biggerStringArray;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first create an empty array which is equal in length to the `stringArray`. Then you can concat the `stringArray` to that new empty array using any Java array concatenation methods.

Here's an example

```
public static String[] method(String[] stringArray) {
    String[] nullArray = new String[stringArray.length];
    String[] biggerStringArray = Stream.of(nullArray, stringArray).flatMap(Stream::of).toArray(String[]::new);

    // for (int i = 0; i < biggerStringArray.length; i++) {
    //     System.out.print(biggerStringArray[i] + ", ");
    // }

    return biggerStringArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String[] method(String[]stringArray) {
    String[] biggerStringArray = Arrays.copyOf(stringArray, stringArray.length * 2);

    List<String> biggerStringList = Arrays.asList(biggerStringArray);
    biggerStringList.sort(Comparator.nullsFirst(String::compareTo));

    System.out.println(biggerStringList);

    return biggerStringList.toArray(new String[biggerStringList.size()]);
}
```